# MapBasic. Where-clause in Select Statement

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic, select

What is wrong with this statement? I reckon the where-clause is the problem.

```
Select * from "BEDIRECT_POT_" + vo_num, PLZ5_2012_bereinigt 
where "BEDIRECT_POT_" + vo_num.PLZ like PLZ5_2012_bereinigt.PLZ 
order by PLZ 
into "BEDIRECT_POT_" + vo_num + "_PLZ"
```

This section seems to be wrong: "BEDIRECT_POT_" + vo_num.PLZ

Answer (score 2):

Agnes

There might be a couple of things wrong with your statement:

**Dynamic SQL statements**

Running a SQL Select like this would either involve Alias variables or the use of Run Command to run the SQL Select statement as a string.

Try this:

```
Dim sTab As String
Dim aCol As Alias
sTab = "BEDIRECT_POT_" + vo_num
sCol = sTab & ".PLZ"

Select * 
   from sTab, PLZ5_2012_bereinigt 
   where aCol = PLZ5_2012_bereinigt.PLZ 
   order by aCol
   into "BEDIRECT_POT_" + vo_num + "_PLZ"
```

Note that I replaced the Like operator with =.

or this:

```
Dim sTab As String
Dim sCmd As String
sTab = "BEDIRECT_POT_" + vo_num

sCmd = "Select * "
   & " from " & sTab & ", PLZ5_2012_bereinigt" 
   & " Where " & sTab & ".PLZ = PLZ5_2012_bereinigt.PLZ" 
   & " Order by " & sTab & ".PLZ"
   & " into "BEDIRECT_POT_" + vo_num + "_PLZ"

Run Command sCmd
```

**Join operator**

You can't join using the Like operator in MapInfo Professional/MapBasic, so you need to use another operator.

I have switch from Like to = in the examples above.

Peter

Comment: Bit rusty on my Mapbasic :)

Comment: Yeah, I guess you need to train your MapBasic muscle a bit again, Nathan ;-)